# Ruby/Sinatra: Load additional code without restarting web app

Tags: ruby, web-applications, sinatra, rack

I want to build a plugin system for a web app I'm writing. I don't want to have to restart the application every time a plugin is added/removed/enabled/disabled. Also I won't know the names of the plugins or even how many there are (I want to make it 'infintely' expandable).

The obvious way would be to reload the app on every request (as in this question, the Sinatra FAQ, and with Sinatra-Contrib). Reloading on every request would have poor performance for a production environment, especially a popular app.

I have read an article about Kernel#load and that it reloads the file when called multiple times and Kernel#autoload which only loads the code if needed. But both methods require the name of the module/class to be hard-coded in.

Jenkins CI and WordPress imply they can do this. Jenkins says "1000+ community contributed Jenkins plugins" and WordPress says "48,492 plugins". So I imagine it must be possible, but maybe only in Java or PHP.

I am working with Ruby 2.2, Rack 1.6.5, and Sinatra 1.4.7. I'm developing on Windows and I plan to deploy to Linux. If what I want is impossible to do on Windows (annoyingly some things are :P) I will set up a dev server with Linux.

Thanks!

EDIT: I will also need to be able to unload plugins. I'm not aware of any unload/un-require methods

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you can use Ruby metaprogramming to send the file, i.e `Kernel.send(:load, filename)` to be able to load files dynamically?

Comment: `Kernel#load` does not "require the name of the module/class to be hard-coded in." Its argument is a string, and that string can come from anywhere and be completely dynamic. If you wanted you could do `10.times { load(some_method_that_returns_random_filenames) }` and load ten different modules.

Comment: various hosts provide zero-downtime updates, but they often spin up temporary servers and redirect traffic there during the reboot. Perhaps you can make some special route which requires an additional password, and pass the argument to `load` in this way

Comment: @maxple can you please explain what you mean by 'special route' and 'pass the argument to `load`'?